# How to display checkbox values in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how would you display the values of multiple checkboxes in a view? Below is an example of what am talking about.

```
<% ExamPaper.all.each do |key, val| %>
    <%= f.check_box :exam_type, {:multiple => true}, key.exam_name, :class => 'exam_type'%>
    <%= key.exam_name %> 
<% end %>
```

In my view i tried displaying the items that were saved in the database like this;

```
<%= exam.exam_type %>
```

and nothing is shown. How would i display the saved items in a rails view?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

`ExamPaper.all.each` will allow you to loop over instances of `ExamPaper` rather than a `|key, val|` pair. It's not entirely clear whether you want to loop over exam papers or some other class called `ExamType` to select a type for the papers.

My guess is you want something closer to:

```
<% ExamPaper.all.each do |paper| %>
  <%= f.check_box :exam_type, { :multiple => true, :class => 'exam_type' }, paper.id %>
  <%= paper.name %> 
<% end %>
```

Assuming that your `exam_papers` have a `name` and an `id` attribute.

Comment: Hi Shadwell. The values of ExamPaper are saved by another model Exam. It's in the Exam view where i want to display the multiple exam_types chosen by a user. As in <%= @exam.exam_type %> which shows nothing.

Comment: Will write an answer to help (I think)

Answer (score 0):

> It's in the Exam view where I want to display the multiple exam_types
>   chosen by a user

This is really about [`ActiveRecord Associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exam_types
    has_many :exams, through: :exam_types
end

#app/models/exam.rb
Class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exam_types
    has_many :users, through: :exam_types
end

#app/models/exam_types.rb
Class ExamType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :exam
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/controllers/exams_controller.rb
def show
   @exam = current_user.exams.find(params[:id])
end

#app/views/exams/show.html.erb
<% @exam.exam_types.each do |exam_type| %>
    <%= exam_type %>
<% end %>
```